# Convert PHP array in Google Charts formated amount by date

Tags: php, arrays

Convert array to Google Charts format, adding dates that were the same.

I need to add title and count of the dates.

I edited the question, with the code I tried

Example:

```
$data = [
    [
        id => 1,
        date => 2021-02-13 19:47:19
    ],
    [
        id => 2,
        date => 2021-02-11 19:47:19
    ],
    [
        id => 3,
        date => 2021-02-11 19:47:19
    ],
    [
        id => 4,
        date => 2021-02-13 19:47:19
    ],
    [
        id => 5,
        date => 2021-02-10 19:47:19
    ],
]
```

To:

```
$data = [
    ['Date', 'Orders'],
    ['13.02', 2],
    ['11.02', 2],
    ['10.02', 1]
]
```

i try:

```
foreach ( $views as $view ) {
    $date = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( $view->post_date ) );
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd-m-Y', $date );
    
    if ( array_key_exists( $date->format('d.m'), $days ) ) {
        $days[$date->format('d.m')] = $days[$date->format('d.m')] + 1;
    } else { 
        $days[$date->format('d.m')] = 1; 
    }
}
```

resulting in

```
Array ( [13.02] => 2 
        [12.02] => 3 
        [11.02] => 1 
        [09.02] => 1 
    )
```

Comment: Did you even attempt step one of this process yet. If so show us what you have managed to write

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, i will edit

Comment: And what does that generate? Show a `print_r($days);` please

Comment: `$data` !== `$views` and `Object` !== `Array` Please try to be consistant in the samples you provide us with

Comment: Array
(
    [13.02] =&gt; 2
    [12.02] =&gt; 3
    [11.02] =&gt; 1
    [09.02] =&gt; 1
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your code to reconvert that array to the one you want

```
$newdays = [];
$newdays[] = ['Date','Orders'];
foreach ($days as $dat => $cnt){
    $newdays[] = [$dat, $cnt];
}
print_r($newdays);
```

Comment: add this in answer: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?= json_encode($newdays); ?>);